# Determine UILabel height for centering when using adjustFontSizeToFitWidth

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have the following cell design where the numeric label shrinks and the "Overall" label is directly underneath.

[image]

I have properly set the `adjustFontSizeToFitWidth` and `minimumFontSize` properties. The font is resizing correctly. However, anchoring the numeric label to the bottom is challenging. Particularly when the font shrinks the gap between the two labels widens and does not appear vertically centered.

I have tried `sizeToFit`, `sizeThatFits`, and using the font's `pointSize`. All unsuccessfully.

I am aware of `sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`, but don't understand why I would need it in combination with `adjustFontSizeToFitWidth`.

Comment: have you tried `sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`?

Comment: I have considered it. See update.

Comment: Can you rephrase your issue? I think I can help you but I'm not quite sure what your exact problem is. It seems like all you need to do is change the frame for the "123" and "Overall" labels after resizing the "123" label.

Comment: The problem is the spacing between the point and "Overall" label, when the point label font resizes. I'd like to keep them *tight together* with the point label potentially centered.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, so you want to position the `UILabels` in the middle of the container view (both horizontally and vertically)?

I have rephrased my answer so it will make more sense to future readers.

My code is assuming that you have the 3 IBOutlets set up:

```
UIView *containerView; //Your nice view containing the two textfields.
UILabel *points; //The label containing the number.
UILabel *overall; //The textfield containing the text 'overall'.
```

You could simply set the frame of the labels **after** assigning the text and calling the `sizeToFit`.

1. This first line positions the `UILabel` points, the only change being that the y coordinate is half of `containerView` subtract half of the height of itself.

   ```
   points.frame = CGRectMake(points.frame.origin.x, (containerView.frame.size.height / 2) - (points.frame.size.height / 2), points.frame.size.width, points.frame.size.height);
   ```
2. To position the `overall` accordingly - say there is a distance of say 6 between the number and overall labels:

   ```
   int space = 6;

   overall.frame = CGRectMake(overall.frame.origin.x, points.frame.origin.y + points.frame.size.height + space, overall.frame.size.width, overall.frame.size.height);
   ```
3. Having read your comments, I think you are after this solution. If you want both `UILabels` to appear in the middle; subtract `(overall.frame.size.height / 2) + (space / 2)` from the y value of `points` like so (with the code of number 2 beneath it):

   ```
   int space = 6;
   points.frame = CGRectMake(points.frame.origin.x, ((containerView.frame.size.height / 2) - (points.frame.size.height / 2)) - ((overall.frame.size.height / 2) + (space / 2)), points.frame.size.width, points.frame.size.height);
   overall.frame = CGRectMake(overall.frame.origin.x, points.frame.origin.y + points.frame.size.height + space, overall.frame.size.width, overall.frame.size.height);
   ```

The final point will produce an output like this image. As you can see the blue line is half of the whole image, and intersects the black rectangle (which is snuggly around the two labels) at its middle point. I hope this is what you were after.

[image: image depicting effect]

Comment: While you are calling it `squareView`, a container view may be they way to go.

Comment: I presume you have a view for the overall score which has this nice background and the dots on the right. I should rename it to whatever that is. It is now `containerView` - much better! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two labels, use `CATextLayer` instead. You will be easily able to make one part BOLD and the other normal. plus position and adjusting size for One layer will be easy relative to placing two labels. shadow setting, line break mode, fonts you will be able to adjust everything beautifully :)

Comment: I'll remember that for the future. But at this point, everything is built as a UILabel and I'd rather not refactor. Plus it's now a challenge :)